# React set state error outside of componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Im getting an error `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.` when I try to set state in my `retrieveRoleMembers` function not sure how to fix it, any feedback is appreciated!

```
class MainCard extends Component {
state = {
    userResponseData:[] ,
    roleResponseDataID:[] 


}

handleChange = (tab) => {

    window.alert(`Tab changed to: ${tab}`);
};

retrieveRoleMembers(){

    var i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < this.props.userRoleDataValue.length; i++) {
        if(this.props.userRoleDataValue[i].role_id === this.state.roleResponseDataID.id){
             for(j=0;j<this.state.userResponseData.length;j++){
                 if(this.props.userRoleDataValue[i].user_id === this.state.userResponseData[j].id)
                 {
                      this.setState({ // This is where the error is happening
                        outputRoleMembers: this.state.userResponseData[j],
                      })

                 }
             }

}}}
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getComponentById(VIEW_ROLES, Roles, this.props.searchValue.value).then(() => {
            return this.setState({ 

                roleResponseDataID: this.props.roles.data,
                cardHandle: false,
            })
            
        });

        this.props.fetchComponent([IS_FETCHING_DBUSERS, FETCH_DBUSERS_SUCCESS], users)
        .then(() => {
            return this.setState({

                userResponseData: this.props.users.data,
            })
        });

}
render() {
    if (this.props.cardHandle) {
        return null
    }
    else {

        if (this.props.sendOptionSelected === 'Role') {
            this.retrieveRoleMembers()
            return (
                <Card mr={'0px'}>
                    <Tabs defaultActiveTab="Members" onChange={this.handleChange} >
                        {/* Group of tabs */}
                        <Tabs.Tab label="Members">Members</Tabs.Tab>
                        <Tabs.Tab label="Access">Access</Tabs.Tab>

                        {/* Tab panels */}
                        <Tabs.Panel label="Members">
                            <Table
                                data={Array.isArray(this.state.outputRoleMembers) ? this.state.outputRoleMembers : [this.state.outputRoleMembers]}
                                defaultPageSize={[this.state.outputRoleMembers].length}
                                columns={
                                    [

                                        {
                                            Header: 'Fisrt Name',
                                            accessor: 'first_name'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            Header: 'Last Name',
                                            accessor: 'last_name'
                                        }

                                    ]
                                }
                                sortable={false}
                                resizable={false}
                                showPagination={false}
                                onSortedChange={() => { }}
                            />
                        </Tabs.Panel>
                    </Tabs>
                </Card>
            )
        }
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            roles: state.roles.item,
            users: state.users
        }
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getComponentById,fetchComponent })(MainCard);
```

and when I change `retrieveRoleMembers` to look like so, my code works but when I inspect the console log I see a infinite loop / renders for `VIEW_DBUSERS`

```
retrieveRoleMembers(){
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.props.userRoleDataValue.length; i++) {
            if(this.props.userRoleDataValue[i].role_id === this.state.roleResponseDataID.id){
                 this.props.getComponentById(VIEW_DBUSERS, users, this.props.userRoleDataValue[i].user_id).then(() => {
                    return this.setState({
                        outputRoleMembers: this.props.users.data,
                   })
                });

    }}}
```

Comment: Where do you call `retrieveRoleMembers`? And why not update the state when you finish the loop, rather than in every iteration?

Comment: Maybe you are calling retrieveRoleMembers from HTML in a wrong way.

Comment: Im calling `retrieveRoleMembers` in my render to populate a table & I don't really have a reason to why Im calling it in the loop, but I figured its more straight forward than having to save an array then later assigned it to `outputRoleMembers` ... any suggestions on how the assignment outside the loop would look like?

Comment: render method called everytime if there is a change in state. So you said you are calling it withing render. That means it will call retrieveRoleMembers method and set the state(as you are setting state insideretrieveRoleMembers ).. and because the state is updated so it will re-render the view. Re-rendering the view mean calling render method again. So It is creating loop. Rather than calling it in render, call it in componentDidMount or some other place.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Please see the render method I added

Comment: @GalAbra Please see the render method I added

Comment: @CatGirl19 Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are calling function inside render method. That `sets the State` and calls the render method again and so on. So it created a loop.

Hence you get

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Maximum update depth exceeded

I put everything inside `componentDidMount` by making an `async` function.

```
    componentDidMount() {
      this.preFetchData(); 
    }
    
    preFetchData async () { // made this async function.. using await to make code sync 
       await this.props.getComponentById(VIEW_ROLES, Roles, this.props.searchValue.value);
       await this.props.fetchComponent([IS_FETCHING_DBUSERS, FETCH_DBUSERS_SUCCESS], users);
    
       this.setState({ roleResponseDataID: this.props.roles.data, cardHandle: false, userResponseData: this.props.users.data }, () => {
            this.retrieveRoleMembers(); // call your method here 
       });
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Always a pleasure..!! Thanks